# Use specific version of Qt Libraries

Tags: qt

I'm using Qt 5.7, but I would like to use an specific library that is from Qt 5.8 version. I was wondering if that is possible. The library I'm trying to use is the QtWebEngine 1.4

Comment: Can't you just upgrade to Qt 5.8? That would be the simplest course of action.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by rebuilding the Qt WebEngine module with your Qt 5.7 build. It is not guaranteed it will work but I've done this before without problems.